# Rename block fields in the Wordpress style dropdown

Tags: wordpress, themes

When selecting block styles in the wp editor (p, h1, h2, etc.) is there a way to change the text in the dropdown? Like instead of showing *Heading 2*, it will show *Subhead*. I think this is more user friendly for those who don't know HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% certain what you mean - I see "Heading 2" rather than H2, and I'm fairly sure I'm using a standard install:

[image: WordPress styles]

If it's those names you want to change, I don't know of a way to change them without changing the core files: `wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/wp-langs-en.js` (for example); it's the block starting `tinyMCE.addI18n("en.advanced"`

Comment: H2 is the accronym of Heading 2.

Comment: Is there a non-Javascript answer? I was thinking along the lines of adding code to `functions.php`.